# VLC media player sound problems in 12.10

Tags: sound, 12.10, vlc

When I try playing .m4v files in VLC the sound track doesn't play correctly, and I get a kind of buzzing staticy distorted version of the actual sound, I'd really appreciate some help as I don't really like totem and XBMC doesn't seem to be working either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Go in to the Preferences and switch the Output Module to ALSA audio output.
Quit VLC & relaunch.
It worked ok  to me

Comment: Do you have a screenshoot of that menu? If you add an image (of the `Preferences` menu), will be more easy to the users to set the configuration as you said.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problems with VLC sound playback in various formats. Go in to the `Preferences` and switch the `Output Module` to `Pulseaudio audio output`.
Quit VLC & relaunch.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

For me 3 things (Easier than other options I could try) worked. You could either:

- Change the Sound Preferences in VLC by going to **Tools --> Preferences --> Sound** and changing the Default from one option to another. For example **Alsa to Pulseaudio** or  **Pulseaudio to Alsa** are the most common ones.
  [image]
- Try pausing the movie for 2 to 5 seconds, then unpause it. The sound should come immediately of after 1 or 2 seconds without the horrible static.
- If you are using HDMI or outputting it to a TV/Monitor with Speakers and already checked all the Sound settings in your TV or Monitor, try changing the Sound Preferences in Ubuntu:

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution #23 worked for me for 2 computers for skype and vlc that made problems with sound: [pulseAudioBugWebSite](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/751265)

The solution is to change the lines in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. I've changed this line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to this:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

reboot. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

None of the Module changes made anything better. Some made it worse. What finally fixed it for me was just unselecting "Enable Time Stretching Audio":

Tools > Preferences > Audio > Enable Time Stretching Audio (uncheck)

This was checked by default (I know because I uninstalled and reinstalled and also reset preferences), so I don't know when it became a problem, but everything checks out now. Output Module is set to Automatic if that makes any difference to anyone.